# How to get the value corresponding to the last day of week 26 from a date range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, week-number

So, the table contains a date range and the challenge is to get the value corresponding to the last day of week 26.
I've tried using index + Match + weeknumber, but it returns nothing.

```
=arrayformula(INDEX(Data!F:F,MATCH(1,(Data!A:A=A2)*(WEEKNUM(Data!B:B))=26),0))
```

Here's the practical exmaple:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NZe359m4zH40ZtJ8O46FVl7yj5n90eiBBt1oM3uyk4Q/edit?usp=sharing

Also, since this is going to be dragged down about 2k rows, index + match seems to be heavy to process. Would there be an alternative?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose to use filter function:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(Data!A:F, Data!A:A=A2, WEEKNUM(Data!B:B)=G1, WEEKDAY(Data!B:B)=G2),"no data for this criteria")
```

This displays columns from A to F where ticker in column A = A2, week number is ffound in G1 and day of the week is found in G2.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the answer. I was wondering if considering the start and final dates in the range, can I get weeknum (let's say 26) to be bound to that range, instead of a regular year?